Gitlab CICD: get current build path
I am doing my first CI project I am getting quite confused with $CI_BUILDS_DIR.
This env gives me the path to builds folder:
D:\block_gitlab_runner\GitLab-Runner\builds
But the current build is at
D:\block_gitlab_runner\GitLab-Runner\builds\vDLVWCgmH\0\<name>\<repo_name>
Is there any ways to get the path to
D:\block_gitlab_runner\GitLab-Runner\builds\vDLVWCgmH\0\<name>\<repo_name>?

the build path is $CI_PROJECT_DIR
